Date range pricker when user selects past date from the daterange picker calendar then allow to select past dates only
I have datarange picker with below code.
Lets say today is sept 20, 2024. From the date range picker if user selects sept 5th then allow him to select till sept 19th only (not after clicking on apply). Should after selecting one date it should disable future dates


$(function() {
        var allowedDates = new Date();
        allowedDates.setDate(allowedDates.getDate() - 30);
        $('input[name="from_to_dates"]').daterangepicker({
            autoUpdateInput: false,
            minDate: allowedDates,
            opens: 'right',
            locale: {
                cancelLabel: 'Clear'
            }
        }).on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            picker.container.addClass('my-custom-css');
        });

        $('input[name="from_to_dates"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            var todaysDate = '<?= date('m/d/Y'); ?>';
            var selectedStartDate = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            var selectedEndDate = picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            if (selectedStartDate == todaysDate && selectedEndDate == todaysDate) {
                $("#day_part_select").prop('disabled', false);
            } else if (selectedStartDate == selectedEndDate) {
                $("#day_part_select").prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $("#day_part_select").val("0").change();
                $("#day_part_select").prop('disabled', true);
            }
            $(this).val(selectedStartDate + ' - ' + selectedEndDate);
        });

        $('input[name="from_to_dates"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).val('<?= date("m/d/Y"); ?>');
        });
   });



